# Excel sorting and data matching

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a large excel sheet with many columns. I do not want to sort columns A - X. Column Z needs to be sorted so the values in column Z = values in column A (A55=Z55).

Column Y is related to column Z (Y22 related to Z22). So column Y and Z must maintain there relationship before and after the sort. Example Data:

```
Column A: A123, A456, A556, B234
Column Y: red, yellow, pink, green
Column Z: A556, A456, B234.
```

How do I sort column Z (and Y)?

Comment: Are you okay with making a new column?

Comment: yes, new columns are fine

Comment: Sorting the first 24 columns does not work in my situation since it will break too many formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Way:

My Array:

[image]

Add Column:

[image]

New Array(s):

[image]

Sort A smallest to largest (important!):

[image]

Sort Z smallest to largest:

[image]

Delete Temp Column and voila:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with adding columns, then instead of directly sorting Y and Z we can essentially create 2 new columns that are the sorted values according to column A.

So if your data looks like this:

```
A     ...  Y        Z
------------------------
A123       red      A556
A456       yellow   A456
A556       pink     B234
B234       green    A123
```

We can create this:

```
A     ...  Y        Z      AA      AB
---------------------------------------
A123       red     A556    A123    green
A456       yellow  A456    A456    yellow
A556       pink    B234    A556    red
B234       green   A123    B234    pink
```

The formula for column AA would be a straight cell reference to column A:

```
=A1, =A2, =A3, etc.
```

The formula for column AB would be a simple index/match combination:

```
=INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(AA1,Z:Z,0))
```

So it would look like this:

```
A     ...  Y        Z       AA                 AB
---------------------------------------------------------------
A123       red     A556    =A1     =INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(AA1,Z:Z,0))
A456       yellow  A456    =A2     =INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(AA2,Z:Z,0))
A556       pink    B234    =A3     =INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(AA3,Z:Z,0))
B234       green   A123    =A4     =INDEX(Y:Y,MATCH(AA4,Z:Z,0))
```